# SSH tries other keys despite specifying a key with -i option

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

For the same user, I have two keys on the local machine. On the remote server, both keys are in the `authorized_keys` file.

I delete one of the keys in the `authorized_keys` file.

I then try to ssh with the other key using the -i option. It succeeds. The auth log shows that the other (undeleted) key in the `authorized_keys` file was used to log in - despite me having tried to use the deleted key with the -i option.

Is this normal behavior?

I would expect that ssh only tried to use the key that was specified with the -i option. I know that when no key is specified it tries them all. Shouldn't that not happen when a key is explicitly specified? Or is it more like, tried the specified key first, then try the rest anyway.

Is the expected behavior documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I should have [searched more thoroughly](https://superuser.com/questions/772660/howto-force-ssh-to-use-a-specific-private-key). There's an option to do just this.

To make SSH use only the specified identity file, I need to use the `-o "IdentitiesOnly=yes"` option:

```
ssh -o "IdentitiesOnly=yes" -i <private key filename> <hostname>
```

> IdentitiesOnly

> Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the configured authentication identity and certificate files (either the default files, or those explicitly configured in the ssh_config files or passed              on the ssh(1) command-line), even if ssh-agent(1) or a PKCS11Provider or SecurityKeyProvider offers more identities.  The argument to this keyword must be yes or no (the default).  This op_              tion is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identities.